# Uploading sourcemaps to Sentry with Heroku deployed react app

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, sentry, source-maps

I have a React project I'm working on, I use Heroku to deploy and manage the app and Sentry to monitor it.

Currently I'm building the app without sourcemaps so the source code will not be available on production. However when I look at Sentry I do want to have the sourcemaps available, to make debugging easier.

Is there a way to deploy a build to production without sourcemaps but have the same build in Sentry with ones?

Thanks in advance